# how can i make a video for my web app?

Tags: video, software-rec, screen-capture, screencasts

I was wondering, is there a tool out there that can help me built a video to explain what my web app does, just like the one in [Google Wave](http://www.youtube.com/googlewave) ?

Comment: You need screen capture software. There are several questions asking for recommendations already on Super User.

Comment: As @ChrisF mentioned, you need a screen capture / screencasting software. Have a look @ [Free Recording/Screencasting software](http://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the free version of [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/).